# How to get from docker swarm docker-stack.yml file for stack

Tags: docker, swarm, docker-stack

There is a working docker swarm cluster. There are several stacks. But the docker-stack.yml files are lost. How to restore them?

Comment: With Kubernets, this would be quite simple, because it allows to get the descriptor for each and every object and display it as yaml. Docker Swarm on the otherhand lacks this functionality. Your best bet is to inspect each service of the stack and reconstruct your stack.yml with the details you get from inspecting the services. For the future you might consider to put your configurations under version control to prevent to loose any configuration again...

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way. swarmpit will allow you to do this.